# Metadata Excel File: What would the Domain and Range be?

Tags: mysql, excel, metadata

I'm creating a metadata excel document for all my tables and I had a quick question.

For zipcode, it has to be 5 digits.

What would the data type be for Domain?

And for Range, is it just 5 or is there some technical way of putting it into the excel document under Range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you mentioned char(5) and later mentioned it as digits. So what exactly are you trying to save. Anyways you can try below options

- CHAR(5) for character/digit which is exactly 5 characters
- VARCHAR(5) for character/digit which is upto 5 characters
- MEDIUMINT for integers between -8388607 to 8388607 ( least memory usage)
- UNSIGNED DECIMAL(5,0) for in integers 0 to 99999

Comment: It's a zipcode so it has to be 5 digits. Therefore I'm using Char(5). My question is specifically about what to put under the Range column for my metadata excel document

Comment: May be you can use DECIMAL or MEDIUM INT, that will make sure junk data is not entered into these column. And keep in mind, zipcode is 6 digit in many countries. I would personally recommend DECIMAL